# Random, truly memorable password generator

Tags: security, password-manager, random-number-generator

I'm looking for a password generator that:

- Generates secure, **truly** memorable passwords such as:

  - `week826]Welcome`
  - `Stick+heavy:359`
  - `Red6.32inch.Who`
  - `Simple9983$front;Has`
  - `niece57]Double%his88`
- Is completely automatic by default (no asking for how many words, how many digits, patterns, etc - just fill up the defined length with whatever fits in whatever order).
- Allows you to set a custom length.

I've found **so** many that don't meet this criteria:

1. https://xkpasswd.net/s/
2. https://passwordsgenerator.net/
3. https://identitysafe.norton.com/password-generator
4. https://lastpass.com/generatepassword.php
5. https://www.random.org/passwords/?mode=advanced
6. https://www.dashlane.com/features/password-generator
7. https://www.comparethemarket.com/credit-cards/information/password-generator/
8. https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/new-password-generator/
9. http://www.generate-password.com/   https://www.safepasswd.com/
10. https://www.warpconduit.net/password-generator/
11. http://generista.com/
12. http://pwgen-win.sourceforge.net/ / https://sourceforge.net/projects/pwgen-win
13. Dashlane's.
14. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xkpasswd
15. KeePass'.

The closest that I've found are:

1. http://www.dinopass.com/ but you can't choose the length and it resorts to common replacements (`@` for `a`, `$` for `s`, `(` for `c`, etc).
2. Safe In Cloud but it's a password manager so you have to unlock it all of the time.

Comment: Apart from thinking I wouldn't remember most of those passwords you'd like: What OS should it run on, and how much would you be willing to pay if needed?

Comment: I think you're assuming that you use online password generator, right?

Comment: Windows or online. I'll consider cost when it comes to it. Thanks.

Comment: If they're memorable, it'very likely that those passwords aren't that secure after all.

Comment: @Alejandro No, it isn't. https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/blog-post/three-random-words-or-thinkrandom-0

Comment: @mythofechelon So if you know that technique yields poor passwords, why use it after all? Why not a normal password manager where you don't even have to know your own password?

Comment: @Alejandro It doesn't yield poor passwords and because quite often I don't have the option of pasting.

Comment: Mandatory [XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've settled for the latest version of [den4b's RandPass](https://www.den4b.com/products/randpass) in passphrase mode with a large word list because the generated passphrases are easily memorable and are extremely secure according to every single password strength checking tool that I can find.

**Update: 2020/02/10 11:55**

https://www.rempe.us/diceware/#eff is also pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Mandatory XKCD reference: 
[image]

Why not just use a dictionary program and choose 4 random words?

Probably because while you could remember the passwords, you wouldn't remember which belongs to which account.

You would need a password manager app for that - at which point you no longer need memorable passwords, so I say that your question is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: I have. See my answer.

I do use a password manager but, as I've said previously, I do need to remember some of the passwords / passphrases because I don't always have the option of using it.

Comment: Exactly my dilemma; I will upvote & examine your answer. Thanks